# Writing a postcard- Every day we eat in a restaurant or we're eating in a restaurant?

Tags: grammar

When writing a postcard from holidays. One should write: We eat in a restaurant or we're eating in a restaurant?
Most sources I've found suggest Present Simple - 'every day'. However in this case it's a temporary situation (a week).....

Comment: Basic questions for learners of English are not suitable for this list. That is the remit of our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: Unless you want to indicate that you're spending all day in the restaurant, if you use _every day_, you want the simple (generic) present, and not the progressive. You can get away with it -- any phrase can be interpreted generically if needed -- but it's not colloquial.